# azure table storage query

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

when I  Post data and Query a Table with the database as: Dev datastorage (emulator) it works.

When I  Post data  Table with the data in Azure data base (have account) it works.
When I  Get data from Table with the data in Azure data base (have account) it does not works.

In both the cases the code is the same.except the key and account credentials.

Is it I should do anything to Query ?

```
    var query = azure.TableQuery
    .select().from('dummytable').where('PartitionKey eq ?', key);
```

can any one suggest why Query is not working.
should there be anything else that need to be done

From Storage Explorer it works, I am able to see the entities.
only from the program I am not able to get the response. But in the same program "PUT"operation is working.

Comment: Not clear what you exactly want. If the querries are working out then what is the issue? Please clarify?

Comment: sorry I made the question more clearer. POST works . Get is not working

Comment: What exception/error you got when retrieving data from table storage?

Comment: There is no Error (or) Exception . get the response but there is no data . if I do the same thing for POST I am getting success response and data is inserted

Comment: Using any storage explorer, can you check if the data is indeed present in the table? Also when working with Azure storage, it may be helpful to trace request/response through a tool like Fiddler. HTH.

Comment: I missed to mention that. From Storage explorer it works thats why I was able to tell that REquest is working and PUT is working. I am running this in Cloud, so you are asking to run fiddler there? I checked the request using Azure-debug statements. looks good. but the response coming from azure is not as  expected. am I missing anything

Comment: So that it easier to try and reproduce accurately - can you share a sample row and the partition key you're using?

Comment: Sorry for the silly slightly off-topic question, but what language are you using for this client app? Is this java? javascript? something else?

Comment: javascript      is the lang used

Answer (score 1):

Was happening the same to me.. did an upgrade from the azure npm package 0.6.1 to 0.6.7 and now works, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the value that is on your partition key.  There are some values that aren't on the list of invalid characters that Azure has issue with.  For example before SDK 1.7 you could safely insert a % in a key, but if you queried for it specifically it wouldn't work.  To test if this is the problem try running your query but without the filter and make sure your row is returned.

Comment: with out any query also I see the same issue. My query partition key is having "Test". I dont see the any special characters. In the localhost this works. I dont understand why it is not working when I try to connect to the server

Comment: In that case it sounds like your data is not getting into the table.  To confirm if the data is there use a data explorer (either the one that is available in VS on the "Server Explorer" window with the Azure SDK or something like Cerebrata Cloud Storage Studio) rather than a query.

Comment: I use azure storage exploerer and I can see the day . I see that data in database..thats what is my main question ....that it is working good from PUT side..but GET is not working

Answer (score 0):

After reading the msdn mailing lists, I have upgraded the azure npm with the latest package 0.6.7 and it works. looks to be an issue with azure